# Textbox textchanged event take only the first caractere

Tags: vb.net, textbox, textchanged

In windows forms , i have a textbox and a combobox , the first for folder name and the second for a subfolder , i want when i type name forlder , automatically the combobox contain the name of subfolder .

But my problem , the textchanged event in textbox , take only **the first caractere**

Here is my code

```
 Private Sub nom_dossier_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nom_dossier.TextChanged

    If (nom_dossier.Text="") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Erreur , Ce dossier n'existe pas ", "Avertissement", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
           nom_sous_dossier.Items.Add(nom_sdossier.Text)       
end sub
```

Comment: The event fires on every key press. You haven't shown your code so it is difficult to help.

Comment: A more typical pattern is to allow the user to type the text and then press a "save" button or similar. If  you don't want the extra step then the `Leave` or `LostFocus` event is more appropriate than `TextChanged`.

Comment: did you copy-paste the code? `nom_dossier` and `nom_sdossier` are definitely not same

Comment: a machine cant know when your word is gonna be finished. So you should do something to help it understands your word in the textbow is finished and you want to add it to combobox , try keypress event and if the pressed key is enter then add the text to the combobox.

Comment: thanks for all , i changed textchanged event to leave event and it's work perfectly